# Cross compiling with arm-musl, ERROR> proc_open: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' in proc_open is referenced > by DSO

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling

I'm trying compile lighttpd to static for processor arm, in order to can run on android device. I'm compiling lighttpd with cross compiler **arm-musl-linuxeabi**, I download it in https://bitbucket.org/GregorR/musl-cross/downloads , When I run make I get error as below:

> /home/ramly/working/arm-linux-musleabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-musleabi/bin/ld:
>   proc_open: hidden symbol `__init_array_end' in proc_open is referenced
>   by DSO
>   /home/ramly/working/arm-linux-musleabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-musleabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-musleabi/bin/ld:
>   final link failed: Bad value

My configuration:

> $ CFLAGS='-static' CC=arm-musl-linuxeabi-gcc AR=arm-musl-linuxeabi-ar
>   RANLIB=arm-musl-linuxeabi-ranlib STRIP=arm-musl-linuxeabi-strip
>   CXX=arm-musl-linuxeabi-g++ ./configure --host=arm-musl-linuxeabi
>   --target=arm-musl-linuxeabi --prefix=/home/ramly/binary/lighttpd --with-sysroot=/home/ramly/working/arm-linux-musleabi/arm-linux-musleabi
>   --without-mysql --without-pcre --without-zlib --without-bzip2 --without-openssl --disable-ipv6 --enable-static --disable-shared

If I run configure I success no problem, No get error, But After configure I run make.

How to fix it? My machine is Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the version of musl you were using. It was fixed by [commit d432b2c057fc64256645422382c2f7e32c45b3cc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/?id=d432b2c057fc64256645422382c2f7e32c45b3cc); the subsequent 0.9.10 release and newer versions have the bug fixed.